# Debugging between JRuby and Java

Tags: java, debugging, jruby, jruby-java-interop

I have a large Java project that uses some Ruby scripts (primarily because of Ruby's support for "yield").  The Ruby code calls Java code which calls more Ruby code.  It's very interleaved, but everything is driven from Java.

I'm using embedded jruby-standalone and building a jar-with-dependencies (via maven).  I'm using a maven plugin to run jrubyc and generate .java files which maven compiles for me.

When I run the jar-with-dependencies, I can attach my debugger to the Java process with no problems, but I'd really love to be able to debug the Ruby code.  Is there a solution for this?

I'm not launching any kind of jruby executable to which I could attach arguments.  It's embedded in the jar and invoked via java -jar.

Comment: If I understand correctly, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with the Ruby plugin supports this kind of cross-language debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the gem [**pry-remote**](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry-remote).

Unlike [pry](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry), it does not require the process to be launched from a terminal (or a terminal emulator if you're on Windows).

It's not really a debugger per se, but if you add `binding.remote_pry` in your code where you wish to observe and react within that context (you could for example catch an exception), this would put pry in waiting mode for a remote connection, and from another terminal you should be able to connect to this process and debug it.

2 minutes hands-on tutorial is available [here](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote/blob/master/README.md).

**Drawbacks:**

- you cannot have 2 pry remote sessions.
- your code must contain the right *'debugging'* condition

I use this in pre-deployment environments when developing web apps with jruby, h2 and jetty server.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Unfortunately we've given up on ruby and just rewrote all the ruby logic into Java (ugly as it may be) so I really can't verify.  But I'll award you the correct answer until somebody comes along and says it doesn't work. =)